# Sql server job to track DB changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a dictionary that holds the updated tables and fields in my db that i keep
to build queries and other stuff.

I want to refresh this dictionary every time a table created or changes.

My solution is to create an sql job that update a table that has boolean value called
IsDBDictionaryUpdated every change.

How can i activate this job by general trigger that jumps every DB structure change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to create a DDL trigger that fires when tables are altered or created. Then, using exec statement, you can execute the job you want to update your dictionary.

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR CREATE_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 

AS
   EXEC msdb..sp_start_job 
       @job_name = 'JobName';
 GO
```

Here's a link to the MS article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx

Comment: Thanks!
Actually i think i can pass on the job and use only the trigger since i only need to update only one field value in my table .

Comment: Sounds like a plan. The DDL trigger is the key.